# Как из C# сделать чертеж в автокад?

Tags: c#, autocad

Мне нужно из C# сделать чертеж в автокад. Чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывался автокад и в нем чертился чертеж, если я все правильно понял, то там создается библиотека, которую нужно подгрузить в автокад.

Подскажите, с помощью каких инструментов это будет лучше всего сделать. Также буду благодарен примеру, как создать чертеж (например, нарисовать прямоугольник).

Comment: Уточните что вы называете чертежем автокада. Есть понятие "векторная графика". Кто то wmf-ку может автокадом называть, например. Автокад поддерживает **несколько** векторных **форматов**, некоторые из них сложнее некоторые легче.

Comment: 2d чертеж в формате dwg

Answer (score 3):

Вообще тема написания плагинов под AutoCAD довольно большая и сложная.
Создаешь в VS проект библиотеки классов. Далее в ссылках добавляешь ссылки на следующие библиотеки "accoremgd.dll", "acdbmgd.dll" и "acmgd.dll" которые лежат в папке, где установлен AutoCAD. Далее в свойствах этих библиотек ставишь, что копировать в выходной каталог их не надо (false). Далее реализуешь в своём классе интерфейс IExtensionApplication

```
public class ACadExt : IExtensionApplication
```

реализуешь два интерфейсных метода void Initialize() и void Terminate().
Для создания своей команды (тот код, что будет выполняться в AutoCAD) помечаешь свой метод атрибутом [CommandMethod()]

```
[CommandMethod("TestCommand")]
public void MyCommand()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Habr!");
}
```

После этого запускаешь AutoCAD, в чертеже вводишь команду "netload" - появляется окно загрузки плагина, выбираешь в нем свою скомпиленную DLL и загружаешь. Теперь когда в строке команды введешь "TestCommand" запустится код, описанный в твоей DLL.

А дальше куришь гугл на предмет как создавать элементы чертежа.

Comment: А есть способ загрузить скомпиленную DDL из c#, чтобы можно было по нажатию кнопки в winform или wpf сразу получить чертеж в автокад? Или только вручную можно?

Comment: Можно с помощью шарпа создать dxf файл и попробовать его запустить, главное чтобы ассоциация стояла на автокад.

Comment: Ivan, а как создать файл с помощью c#?